# Laravel 5.7 eloquent query with multiple wheres and a whereNotIn

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I'm attempting to execute a query that gets a data set based on a user id matching two possible columns and a workflow_state not matching two values. My attempt is here:

```
$usersBugs = Bug::where('assigned_user_id', $user->id)
                ->orWhere('reported_by', $user->id)
                ->whereNotIn('workflow_state', ['closed', 'rejected'])
                ->get();
```

It is returning a "bug" with a rejected `workflow_state`. I'm guessing it is executing the whereNotIn as an or? How would I refactor this to execute that the bug cannot be in either of those two states (no matter what) and it can match either the `assigned_user_id` OR the `report_by`. I tried leading with the whereNotIn:

```
$usersBugs = Bug::whereNotIn('workflow_state', ['closed', 'rejected'])
                ->where('assigned_user_id', $user->id)
                ->orWhere('reported_by', $user->id)
                ->get();
```

Either way it is returning a matched bug based on the `assigned_user_id`, despite the fact that the workflow_state is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `where` .. `orWhere` into additional closure:

```
$usersBugs = Bug::where(function($q) {
  $q->where('assigned_user_id', $user->id)
                    ->orWhere('reported_by', $user->id)
})->whereNotIn('workflow_state', ['closed', 'rejected'])->get();
```

Comment: I was first! :D haha, but same stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
$model->whereNotIn(...)->where(function($query) use ($user) {
   $query->where('assigned_user_id', $user->id)->orWhere('reported_by', $user->id);
})->get();
```